# Android: Service without Activity and Threads

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, service

I have an activity which starts a service, then closes itself (finish())

So if I have the activity start 2 services instead of one, and then close itself, will each service get it's own thread or should I put the 2nd one on it's own?

Comment: Each service will get different threads and perform asynchronously.

Comment: Normal Service runs on main thread, IntentService runs on a seperate thread.

Comment: @WenChao or if I start the 2nd service as a normal one, could I put the work within that service on a new thread via the normal new thread means?

Comment: Yes you can, however Service is designed for long running work, if you want more compact and easier solution, you can choose to use IntentService

Comment: @WenChao ok great, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Services run in main thread, if you havn't created thread in service. So if you have created thread in service then there will be two different thread and if not then there will be only main thread.